# How to escape special chars in PHP iconv_substr?

Tags: php, magento

I found that magento is using iconv_substr function to cut out extra characters. But it breaks when there are special characters. e.g. question mark(?). Is there way to fix this issue?

```
Notice: iconv_substr() [function.iconv-substr]: Detected an illegal character in input string  in Core/Helper/String.php on line 98

app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/String.php(98): iconv_substr('Natural Foam?Co...', 0, 255, 'UTF-8')

catalog/Block/Product/View.php(42): Mage_Core_Helper_String->substr('Natural Foam?Co...', 0, 255)
```

**UPDATE 1:**

I am trying to override magento's view.php and use **iconv** with **//ignore** but that didn't help too, still getting same error.

see code: https://github.com/dbashyal/magento-product-view-meta/blob/master/app/code/community/Technooze/Tcatalog/Block/Product/View.php

**UPDATE 2:**

Used **@** to suppress php notice for above error and is fine for now. see above link for the code. So, it's **[SOLVED]** for me now.

Comment: What version of php are you running?

Comment: PHP 5.3.17 (cli) (built: Oct 17 2012 18:03:17)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.2.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by ionCube Ltd.

Comment: Also, i have PHP 5.3.8 on my wamp and i am not getting any error. It's only showing on staging server with php version mentioned above.

Comment: Using @ is not a solution, you're only hiding the bug and you'll never know if it get worse because PHP won't never ever warn you about a bug on this line. @ should never be used in PHP (besides a few exceptions)

Comment: @Bixi What would be your recommendation then?

Comment: @DamodarBashyal Did you try replacing it with mb_substr?